# Finding all odd numbers divisible by 5

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to code a program which shows odd numbers that are divisible by 5, but it isn't working. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
def show_odd_numbers(min, max):     #this program shows odd numbers divisible by 5.      
    show_odd_numbers = range(5,81)     
    for numbers in range(min,max):       
        if numbers % 5 == 0:         
            show_odd_numbers.count     
    print(show_odd_numbers)
```

Comment: Sorry if the indention did not follow. I know how to indent them. Dont mind it.

Comment: Please update your question with some sample calls and their corresponding outputs and the required outputs.

Comment: What's wrong? What happens? What should it do? What have you tried?

Comment: Your loop doesn't do anything. It potentially accesses a slot and discards the result. Your code is equivalent to `print(range(5, 81))`

Comment: We do mind the indentation. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues: you're not checking that the number is odd, you're not using `min` and `max` (which aren't variable names you should be using, since those are the names of built-ins), and `.count` is probably not something you're really looking for. Here is a code snippet that resolves all of these issues:

```py
def show_odd_numbers(lower, upper):
    for number in range(lower, upper + 1):       
        if number % 5 == 0 and number % 2 == 1:         
            print(number)
            
show_odd_numbers(5, 81)
```

This outputs:

```py
5
15
25
35
45
55
65
75
```

Comment: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50...?

Comment: Can do this too `if number & 1 and number % 5 == 0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a code which returns the odd numbers divisible by 5 on a range.
The code you need:

```
import numpy as np
def show_odd_numbers(min, max):     #this program shows odd numbers divisible by 5. 
    results = []
    for number in np.arange(min,max):       
        if number % 5 == 0 and number % 2 ==1:         
            results.append(number)
    return(results)
```

The apply the function

```
show_odd_numbers(1,20)
```

Output:

```
[5,15]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check and adjust the lower bound appropriately you can reduce the amount of looping needed to get the required output. For example:

```
def show_odd_numbers(lower, upper, n=5):
    if lower % n != 0:
        lower += n
        lower -= lower % n
    if lower % 2 == 0:
        lower += n
    return range(lower, upper+1, n*2)

for n in show_odd_numbers(1, 20):
    print(n)
```

**Output:**

```
5
15
```

**Note:**

This will only work if n is an odd number